# Input/Output error while creating a sensor object in Python - can run in Debugging mode but not otherwise

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run some code to control an accelerometer (Adafruit), which has a pre-written package (adafruit_circuitpython_mma8451). Even before doing anything, just creating the sensor object gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dhoang97/Pi/Acce-Project/acce-project.py", line 10, in <module>
    sensor = adafruit_mma8451.MMA8451(i2c)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dhoang97/Pi/Acce-Project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_mma8451.py", line 129, in __init__
    while self._read_u8(_MMA8451_REG_CTRL_REG2) & 0x40 > 0:
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dhoang97/Pi/Acce-Project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_mma8451.py", line 161, in _read_u8
    self._read_into(address, self._BUFFER, count=1)
  File "/home/dhoang97/Pi/Acce-Project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_mma8451.py", line 157, in _read_into
    i2c.write_then_readinto(bytes([address & 0xFF]), buf, in_end=count)
  File "/home/dhoang97/Pi/Acce-Project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 140, in write_then_readinto
    self.i2c.writeto_then_readfrom(
  File "/home/dhoang97/Pi/Acce-Project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/busio.py", line 224, in writeto_then_readfrom
    return self._i2c.writeto_then_readfrom(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dhoang97/Pi/Acce-Project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py", line 98, in writeto_then_readfrom
    readin = self._i2c_bus.read_i2c_block_data(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dhoang97/Pi/Acce-Project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 264, in read_i2c_block_data
    ioctl(self._device.fileno(), I2C_RDWR, request)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Here's the code (I already commented out everything that complicates the code to run the simplest thing)

```
import board
import time
import adafruit_mma8451

i2c = board.I2C() # user board.SCL and board.SDA
sensor = adafruit_mma8451.MMA8451(i2c)
```

which turns out to be pretty similar to the Simple test here: https://docs.circuitpython.org/projects/mma8451/en/latest/examples.html

I ran this file both through Thonny or through command line in a virtual environment, and both return the same error. I saw multiple threads suggesting it's an SSH problem - I tried running it through SSH and directly from the RPi with GUI, still have the same problem.

Now here's the weird thing: when I run this code using the Debugging mode in Thonny, it does not return any error!

`i2cdetect -y 1` shows the device is active

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYd00.png)

Any idea what might be going wrong here? I'm pretty new to this so any explanation/suggestion would be appreciated.